# from My magento How Can i Get Recent Viewed Product in my new Block

Tags: magento-1.9

from My magento How Can i Get Recent Viewed Product in my new Block

[![i got the related products but how can i get recent viewed Products.......?
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAWTO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAWTO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the the product detail template (view.phtml) you have to be more specific in the xml where you want to place the block. See the example below using local.xml in the theme layout directory (app/design/frontend/your package/your theme/layout/local.xml) to insert the block. Here's an example from a site I'm working on. Ironically we are having problems with it displaying consistently, which I'm trying to figure out right now, but this is working most of the time! Try getting more specific in your catalog.xml and it should work. The xml is in local.xml, the echo is in catalog/product/view.phtml

---

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('recently_viewed') ?>

<catalog_product_view> 
<reference name="content"> 
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="left.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" as="recently_viewed" />
    </reference>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this block for recently viewed products

```
{{block type="reports/product_viewed" name="reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}
```